# Why doesn't ImmutableMap.builder().build() pick the correct type parameters?

Tags: java, guava

Why does `Map<String, ?> test = ImmutableMap.builder().build();` fail to compile, but `Map<String, ?> test = ImmutableMap.<String, Object>builder().build();` work fine?

The first code sniplet fails with:

```
error: incompatible types
  Map<String, ?> test = ImmutableMap.builder().build();
                                                   ^
  required: Map<String,?>
  found:    ImmutableMap<Object,Object>
```

I believe the Guava committers meant for this to work.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is not a failure in Guava, but rather in the way Java resolves generics, and it's something we can't control.  =(

Believe us: this is something that we spent a *lot* of time on.  In this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=883), Kevin mentions that we attempted no less than fifteen approaches for trying to get it so that you didn't have to explicitly specify these type parameters.

If you're only interested in the case of `ImmutableMap.builder().build()`, that is, with no entries in the map...then you should be using `ImmutableMap.of()`.  That won't have any funny issues with generics: it'll just work.

Comment: Is this something that could be fixed in the language? That is, can we file a bug report with Oracle?

Comment: Not...likely, I'm afraid.  If they didn't include it in the augmented type inference with the diamond operator in Java 7, I doubt they can include it at all.  There are probably some weird edge cases that would be impossible to manage for some reason, but I'm not sure of the specifics.

Comment: @Gili: I know there's some work going on to improve type inference for Java 8... this _may_ be something that can be inferred with the improved rules, I'm not sure.