# java type inference in builder pattern

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, type-inference, builder

i want to create a parameterized (generic) class `MyType<T>` and its builder. builder will have some methods that ignore the type `T` and some methods that use the type. but it seems like using this pattern i have to repeat the `T` declaration:

```
                     how to omit this declaration?
                                   |
                                   V
MyType<String> myType = Builder.<String>of()
                               .method1(argument_can_be_of_any_type)
                               .method2(argument_must_be_of_type_T = String)
                               .build();
```

is it possible to use some java syntax tricks or other design patterns to  omit the second type declaration and make the API more user friendly? like for example:

```
List<String> aList = Lists.emptyList();
```

or

```
List<String> aList = new LinkedList<>();
```

i don't want to enforce any order of methods in the builder

Comment: Please post `Builder` class.

Comment: Does the argument to method2 need to be of type String? (In other words, can we infer the eventual type of the return value from build() from that argument? Or can it be just anything?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058430/why-doesnt-immutablemap-builder-build-pick-the-correct-type-parameters

Comment: @ChrisRaser yes, argument of method2 must be a string. that's what i want to achieve - infer type `T` from that argument without explicit declaration

Comment: @piotrek, I've posted a revised solution below (with helpful suggestions from others).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reworked things a bit since my original answer didn't work as advertised. (Thanks to shmosel for spotting the problem, and to Daniel Pryden for the suggested solution.)

```
/* contents of Box.java */
public class Box<T>
{
    private T contents;
    private Object data;

    protected Box(T contents, Object data) {
        this.contents = contents;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public static BoxBuilder builder() {
        return new BoxBuilder();
    }

    public T getContents() {
        return contents;
    }
}

/* contents of BoxBuilder.java */
public class BoxBuilder
{
    private Object data;

    public BoxBuilder withAnything(Object o) {
        this.data = o;
        return this;
    }

    // Infers new type from argument
    public <T> TypedBoxBuilder<T> withBoxContent(T contents) {
        TypedBoxBuilder<T> builder = new TypedBoxBuilder<T>();
        builder.setData(data);
        builder.setContents(contents);

        return builder;
    }
}

/* contents of TypedBoxBuilder.java */
public class TypedBoxBuilder<T>
{
    private T contents;
    private Object data;

    public TypedBoxBuilder() {
    }

    public TypedBoxBuilder<T> withAnything(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
        return this;
    }

    public TypedBoxBuilder<T> withContents(T contents) {
        this.contents = contents;
        return this;
    }

    public Box<T> build() {
        return new Box<T>(contents, data);
    }

    public void setContents(T contents) {
        this.contents = contents;
    }

    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

And here's the client code:

```
Box<String> box = Box.builder() // Returns BoxBuilder
        .withBoxContent("FOO") // Returns TypedBoxBuilder<String>
        .withAnything(42) // Returns TypedBoxBuilder<String>
        .build(); // Returns Box<String>
String c = box.getContents();
```

And this works as well:

```
Box<String> box = Box.builder() // Returns BoxBuilder
        .withAnything(42) // Returns BoxBuilder
        .withBoxContent("FOO") // Returns TypedBoxBuilder<String>
        .build(); // Returns Box<String>
String c = box.getContents();
```

Comment: This is a terrible idea. The generic parameter is useless if you're using a raw type, not to mention that it'll erase any unrelated generics in the same statement. Did you miss this `method2(argument_must_be_of_type_T)`?

Comment: This is so close. What you need is two builder types, `Builder` and `TypedBuilder<T> extends Builder`. Then `builder()` can return `Builder` (not generic) and `withBoxContent(T)` can return `TypedBuilder<T>`.

Comment: @shmosel, nice catch. I didn't see the problem of erasing the other generics. The code compiled and ran correctly, but when I saw your comment I checked and you're right-- it's not type-safe. And Daniel, I see where you're going, I think, and I tinkered a little with it, but it still has the problem shmosel spotted. I *would* like to see a nice way to do something like this (safely infer the type of the built instance from arguments to the Builder), but I don't see a way to make it work.

Comment: @shmosel, Daniel, I'm trying to redeem myself. I took both of your suggestions and put something together that at least works as advertised. I'm still not 100% sold on all this being a good idea, but I'll give piotrek some leeway given the limited context.

Comment: Good effort to have improved your answer. It seems rather fine now. +1.